# Inherited method is giving me the null value

Tags: java, inheritance

I have three classes named ChildClass, BaseClass and Student. ChildClass extends BaseClass. My ChildClass inherits a method called dipslayName() which should print the name of the student but it is giving me the null value. If I comment the student object in my ChildClass it is working fine.

```
package com.techmahindra;

public class ChildClass extends BaseClass{
    Student student = new Student();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChildClass child = new ChildClass();
        child.displayName();
    }

    /*public void displayName(){
        setName();
        System.out.println(student.getName());
    }*/
    public void setName(){
        student.setName("Mahesh");
    }
}
```

This is the other class:

```
package com.techmahindra;

import com.techmahindra.Student;

public class BaseClass {
    Student student = new Student();
    public void displayName(){
        setName();
        System.out.println(student.getName());
    }
    public void setName(){
        student.setName("santhosh");
    }
}
```

This is the other class:

```
package com.techmahindra;

public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two different `student` fields - one in `BaseClass` and one in `ChildClass`. I strongly suspect you don't want that.

Comment: **1** You've commented out the function, so how do you expect it to work? **2** It's a void function, so where is it ‘*giving*’ you null? **3** Both implementations of the function are the same. What's up with that?!

Comment: You have defined a member variable `student` in `BaseClass` as well as in `ChildClass`. Note that these are two separate variables.

Comment: Delete this line `Student student = new Student();` from your `ChildClass`.

Comment: @Biffen even if I comment it out, as the method displayName() is inherited in ChildClass it thinks that I have declared it right? if yes, then it would be something like this. `public class ChildClass extends BaseClass{
 Student student = new Student();
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
     ChildClass child = new ChildClass();
     child.displayName();
    }
 
    public void displayName(){
     setName();
     System.out.println(student.getName());
    }
 public void setName(){
  student.setName("Mahesh");
 }
}`

Comment: @santhosh2759 I've read your comment a few times now, and I just can't seem to understand what you're trying to say. Sorry.

Comment: displayName() method has a print statement and it is printing the null value - @Biffen

Comment: @santhosh2759 So that's what you meant by ‘*giving me*’? OK then.The actual issue has been pointed out by the other commenters. It surprises me that neither the compiler nor your IDE warned you about it.

Comment: Thank you - @Jesper I have confused with the same reference name student in both the classes and now it is clear. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setName()` method within your `ChildClass` sets the name of the student that is declared within your `ChildClass`.
The `displayName()` displays the name of the student as it is declared within the `BaseClass`.
Thus, removing the declaration of the `student` within the ChildClass, the `setName` method will set the name of the correct student.

Within your ChildClass you commented out the overridden method `displayName`. This would correctly display the name of the student as it is declared within your ChildClass.

The fact that both classes contain a variable with the same name creates some confusion.

Answer (score -1):

I have given different reference names and this is how it thinks. So here I am trying to call name of student1 instead of student2. This is what happens if we give same name for references ;)

package com.techmahindra;

public class ChildClass extends BaseClass{
    Student student2 = new Student();

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ChildClass child = new ChildClass();
    child.displayName();
}

/*public void displayName(){
    setName();
    System.out.println(student.getName());
}*/

public void displayName(){   //this method is inherited and not present in this class

    setName();
    System.out.println(student1.getName());
}

public void setName(){
    student2.setName("Mahesh");
}
```

}